# ioncube "the path/to/file.php is corrupted" error

Tags: php, wordpress, ioncube

I have a wordpress website and after installing a plugin suddenly it has been crashed and I got an error saying "The file /home/omdikalc/public_html/wp-content/themes/martfury/functions.php is corrupted.".
The file that the error is refering to is the function.php file of my theme and the file is encoded with ioncube and contains this part of code that raises the error:

```
    <?php //00543
    // Encoded by www.Rtl-Theme.com
    // Encoded at 24 August 2018 - 15:14:53
    if (!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')) {
        $__oc = strtolower(substr(php_uname(), 0, 3));
        $__ln = 'ioncube_loader_' . $__oc . '_' . substr(phpversion(), 0, 3)         . (($__oc == 'win') ? '.dll' : '.so');
        if (function_exists('dl')) {
            @dl($__ln);
        }
        if (function_exists('_il_exec')) {
            return _il_exec();
        }
        $__ln   = '/ioncube/' . $__ln;
        $__oid  = $__id = realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));
        $__here = dirname(__FILE__);
        if (strlen($__id) > 1 && $__id[1] == ':') {
            $__id   = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($__id, 2));
            $__here = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($__here, 2));
        }
        $__rd = str_repeat('/..', substr_count($__id, '/')) . $__here . '/';
        $__i  = strlen($__rd);
        while ($__i--) {
            if ($__rd[$__i] == '/') {
                $__lp = substr($__rd, 0, $__i) . $__ln;
                if (file_exists($__oid . $__lp)) {
                    $__ln = $__lp;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (function_exists('dl')) {
            @dl($__ln);
        }
    } else {
        die('The file ' . __FILE__ . " is corrupted.\n");
    }
    if (function_exists('_il_exec')) {
        return _il_exec();
    }
    echo ("Site error: the " . (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? 'ionCube' : '<a         href="http://www.ioncube.com">ionCube</a>') . " PHP Loader needs to be installed. This is a widely used PHP extension for running ionCube protected PHP code, website security and malware blocking.\n\nPlease visit " . (php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? 'get-loader.ioncube.com' : '<a href="http://get-loader.ioncube.com">get-loader.ioncube.com</a>') . " for install assistance.\n\n");
    exit(199);
    ?>
```

I contacted with my theme provider and they said nothing is wrong with the code and the problem is with the host server.
I contected with my website host service provider and they said the ioncube is running on server properly.
what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

"is corrupted" (as opposed to "is corrupt") comes from the PHP preamble at the start of an ionCube file and indicates that the ionCube Loader did not consider the file as being possibly an ionCube file; if it had the preamble would never get executed as the Loader would have taken over processing the file. One cause would be from making a significant change to the size of the text that appears before the encoded data, such as beautifying the normally compact PHP code as has been done here. You should ensure that you are using the original, unmodified files provided by the script provider, and if still stuck contact ionCube support. If you receive an "is corrupt" message this typically indicates that the Loader has recognised the file as an ionCube file but it was damaged, such as by removing copyright text that a developer has embedded.